# Docker with nodeBB redis is not configured properly?

Tags: node.js, docker, redis

So everything is working well with my project image expect for redis. I was able to build and run, I am happy about that but inside my config.json I have tried changing the host to `redis`, `127.0.0.1`, and the ip of my VM. When I run my nodeBB inside my container I get this issue `error: Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379`

```
"redis": {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": "6379",
    "database": "0"
}
```

I am really not sure where to point to my redis?

Comment: Is Redis within a separate container, in the same container, or just on the host itself? If it's on the host itself, what OS are you running?

Answer (score 1):

Actually docker use its own network(usually is docker0) and has its own IP address,  not `127.0.0.1`. To get the real ip of your container, you can execute command `docker inspect` to find it.

```
docker inspect CONTAINER_IP
```